# javascript replace array’s elements with their respective innerHTML

Tags: javascript

In javascript, how can I do, with elegant code, that:

```
[div#id1, div#id2, ...]
```

replace the array’s elements with their respective `innerHTML` like so

```
[div#id1.innerHTML, div#id2.innerHTML, ...]
```

without using loops but with something built into js like for example the `.filter()` fuction for being clean and concise.

The arrays can also be `HTMLCollections`; it’s no problem.

And I surely prefer a solution that covers all the field variables of the elements, and not only their `innerHTML`.

Comment: thanks for the edit. still new to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map()`

```
newArray = array.map(div => div.innerHTML)
```